# Unexpected end of string error

Tags: javascript

```
debugger; 
   // var header = '<html><head><title>Payment Details</title> <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" /> <link href="../Content/Kendostyle/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="print" />  <link href="../Content/Kendostyle/kendo.uniform.min.css"   media="print" rel="stylesheet" />  <link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/> <link href="../Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/></head><body>';

    var header = '<html><head><title>Payment Details</title><link href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"All\" /> </head><body>';
    //var footer = '</body></html>';
    var w = window.open();
    var printstring = $("#printwrapper").html() + '</body></html>';
    w.document.write(header);
    w.document.write(printstring);
   // w.document.write(footer);
    w.document.close();
    w.focus();
    w.print();
```

Comment: Its shows unexpected end of input

Comment: Which is it, unexpected end of string, or unexpected end of input? You probably have an unmatched `{` somewhere.

Comment: You don't need to escape `"` inside `'`.

Comment: I don't get any error from the code you've posted, it must be coming from something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var header = '<html><head><title>Payment Details</title><link href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"All\" /> </head><body>';
```

You are escaping quote `"` with backslash `\` but it's not necessary because you're enclosing the string with apostrophe `'`. Remove the backslashes `\` as below:

```
var header = '<html><head><title>Payment Details</title><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="All" /> </head><body>';
```

There may be other issues, but this is at least one place to start. I don't see other errors in the partial code you've included in your question.

Comment: What changed? And how does it fix the problem?